# Backbone Model object passed between Alloy controllers have null properties

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, backbone-model

I've started using titanium yesterday and i'm using the 'Creating your first titanium app' tutorial ([this one](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Creating_Your_First_Titanium_App)).

When it gets on the part that you click on a row and it opens another view, my argument values are null. Here's my code:

Bookdetails.js

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
$.titleLabel.text = args.Title || 'Default Title';
$.authorLabel.text = args.Author || 'Default Author';
```

index.js

```
var myBooks = Alloy.Collections.Books;
var myBook = Alloy.createModel('Books', {Title:'Bleach',Author: 'Kubo Tite'});

myBooks.add(myBook);
myBook.save();

function showBook(event){
    var selectedBook = event.source;
    var args = {'Title': selectedBook.Title, 'Author': selectedBook.Author};    
    var bookDetails = Alloy.createController("Bookdetails",args).getView();
    bookDetails.open();
}

$.index.open();
```

Bookdetails.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Label id="titleLabel"></Label>
      <Label id="authorLabel"></Label> 
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

And my Books (model) definition:

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
        columns: {
            "Title": "text",
            "Author": "text"
        },
        adapter: {
            type: "sql",
            collection_name: "Books"
        }
    },
    extendModel: function(Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Model;
    },
    extendCollection: function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Collection;
    }
};
```

Index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection src="Books" />
    <Window class="container">

        <TableView dataCollection="Books">
            <TableViewRow onClick="showBook" title="{Title}"></TableViewRow>
        </TableView>

        <Menu id="menu" platform="android">
            <MenuItem id="addBooks" title="Adicionar" onClick="callAddBook"  showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM" />
        </Menu>

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

When i run my app, it show 'Default Author' and 'Default Title'. I'm running the app on android (samsung s3)

Comment: Could you provide source of `index.xml` file? Looks like the problem occurs on line `var selectedBook = event.source;` but without index.xml it's hard to figure out how event.source looks like.

Comment: Edited with index.xml code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are handling event triggered by TableView in event.source you don't get Backbone Object which was used to generate for that row but [`Titanium.UI.TableViewRow`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow) object.

Also it's better to access `event.row` instead of `event.source` when you are operating on TableView ([check documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow-event-click) to see difference).

To make this example work just change showBook function to:

```
function showBook(event){
    var selectedBook = myBooks.where({Title: event.row.title})[0];
    var args = {'Title': selectedBook.get('Title'), 'Author': selectedBook.get('Author')};
    var bookDetails = Alloy.createController("Bookdetails", args).getView();
    bookDetails.open();
}
```

Also instead of creating new `args` object and sending it to Bookdetails controller you can send unmodified Backbone Model object to make easier any further modifications on it:

```
function showBook(event){
    var selectedBook = myBooks.where({Title: event.row.title})[0];
    var bookDetails = Alloy.createController("Bookdetails", selectedBook).getView();
    bookDetails.open();
}
```

*Bookdetails.js*

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

$.titleLabel.text = args.get('Title') || 'Default Title';
$.authorLabel.text = args.get('Author') || 'Default Author';
```

Comment: It worked! It clarified some stuff about the arguments too. Thanks!